# Django get SUM of function result from all objects

Tags: python, django, function, django-models, django-views

Something tells me this question is going to be very obvious but I've been stuck on it since all the searching I've done basically ends on calculating the sum of all objects which is what context['all_trades'] does. However, I'm looking to calculate the sum of all object results calculated in a function. I hope this is properly worded.

If I print out the context this is the result:

```
{'view': <portfolios.views.StatsView object at 0x0000020CC8B0D188>, 'all_trades': 13, 'gross_profit': <function Trade.get_profit_loss_value at 0x0000020CC70598B8>}
```

models.py

```
class Trade(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Trade"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trades"

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    ...

    # P/L Value = Sum of all buys * ( Entry Cost Per Unit (CPU) - Exit Cost Per Unit (CPU) )
    def get_profit_loss_value_or_None(self):
        if self.get_exit_cpu() > 0:
            if self.type == 'Long':
                result = self.get_entries().aggregate(
                get_profit_loss_value=Sum('amount', output_field=models.FloatField()
                                           ) * (self.get_exit_cpu() - self.get_entry_cpu()))['get_profit_loss_value']
            return 0 if result is None else result
        elif self.type == 'Short':
            result = self.get_entries().aggregate(
            get_profit_loss_value=Sum('amount', output_field=models.FloatField()
                                           ) * -1 * (self.get_exit_cpu() - self.get_entry_cpu()))['get_profit_loss_value']
            return 0 if result is None else result
        else:
            return 0

    def get_profit_loss_value(self):
        ret = self.get_profit_loss_value_or_None()
        return 0 if ret is None else ret
```

views.py

```
class StatsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # get # of trades user made
        context['all_trades'] = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
        # get sum of all trades profit/loss
        context['gross_profit'] = Trade.get_profit_loss_value 
        return context
```

---

Based on Dean Elliott's answer so far made adjustments to views.py

```
class StatsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/stats.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        trade = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        context = super(StatsView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['all_trades'] = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
        context['gross_profit'] = trade.get_profit_loss_value()
        #context['net_profit'] = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).count()
        print(context['gross_profit'])
        return context
```

results in error:

```
line 352, in get_context_data
    context['gross_profit'] = trade.get_profit_loss_value()
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_profit_loss_value'
```

Comment: what's inside self.get_profit_loss_value_or_None() ?

Comment: More calculations, it goes on for quite a bit (all inside the Trade class)

Comment: I know where it is but I don't know what is it. The point is, you want to use database aggregation to get sum of something from your trade table. Depending on the logic of this function it might be more or less complicated.

Comment: valid point, I added the get_profit_loss_value_or_None function. Not sure how much more you need but it's a lot more functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `get()` method instead of `filter()` while getting `trade` in `get_context_data()` method as below...

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    trade = Trade.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
```

instead of...

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    trade = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

**OR**

If you want to use `filter()` then use `first()` for getting single object from it as below...

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    trade = Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    ... YOUR LOGIC ...
    profit_loss = sum([t.get_profit_loss_value() for t in trade])
    context['gross_profit'] = profit_loss
    ... YOUR LOGIC ...
```

So, it will give you first element from `queryset`.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt! 1st solution gave me error "get() returned more than one Trade -- it returned 13!" 2nd solution returned 0 instead of the actual answer.

Comment: For 1st, yes if there is more than one object having the same `user` in the `Trade` model it will give you more than one Trade. But with the use of `filter` and `first`, you will get `0`. So, I want to know what is your desire output and how you can calculate it?

Comment: I think you have to call `get_profit_loss_value()` method for all object which you will get using `Trade.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)` and sum of all that value will set to `context['gross_profit']`, right?

Comment: sum([t.get_profit_loss_value() for t in trade]) this was the trick. Awesome solution MK Patel, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Always, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a `Trade` object for `context['gross_profit'] = Trade.get_profit_loss_value`. For example `trade = Trade.objects.get(id=1)` and then use `trade.get_profit_loss_value()`.

Be sure to add the brackets as well! Without the brackets you are only referencing the function, not actually calling it.